# How to list down all webcams in jComboBox? (sarxos library)

Tags: java, jcombobox

I have two webcams. Is it possible to list down all webcam devices in jComboBox?

[image]

```
public class pasporcheckin extends javax.swing.JFra {
private Dimension ds = new Dimension(450, 360);
private Dimension cs = WebcamResolution.VGA.getSize();
```

Here I have set webcam on device one!

```
private Webcam wcam = Webcam.getWebcams().get(1);
private WebcamPanel wcampanel = new WebcamPanel((Webcam) wcam, ds, false);

/**
 * Creates new form pasporcheckin
 */
public pasporcheckin() {
  initComponents();
  wcam.setViewSize(cs);
  wcampanel.setFillArea(true);
  panelCam.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
  panelCam.add(wcampanel);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you add second camera in same way?

```
private Webcam wcam = Webcam.getWebcams().get(1);
private WebcamPanel wcampanel = new WebcamPanel((Webcam) wcam, ds, false);

private Webcam wcam2 = Webcam.getWebcams().get(2);
private WebcamPanel wcampanel2 = new WebcamPanel((Webcam) wcam2, ds, false);

/**
 * Creates new form pasporcheckin
 */
public pasporcheckin() {
  initComponents();

  wcam.setViewSize(cs);
  wcam2.setViewSize(cs);

  wcampanel.setFillArea(true);
  wcampanel2.setFillArea(true);

  panelCam.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

  panelCam.add(wcampanel);
  panelCam.add(wcampanel2);

}
```